# Largest product in a series in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

The four adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product are:

`9 × 9 × 8 × 9 = 5832`

```
73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450
```

Find the thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product. What is the value of this product?

My solution to this problem is:

```
def no(x):
    previous=0
    i=0
    t=1
    while i !=987:
        for num in x[i:i+13]:
            no=int(num)
            t=no*t

        if  t>previous:
            previous = t
        i=i+1
        t=1
    return previous
```

Are there any other good and efficient ways to solve this problem ? because I think mine is not very efficient

Comment: Your solution still works in linear time so it's going to be hard to improve the efficiency outside of adding some short circuit heuristics.

Comment: Your code is in O(n), speaking in complexity class, it won't get faster. However, what you could do to reduce the factor, instead of doing the whole multiplication new every time, you could keep the number and in every step divide by the digit that is removed and multiplicate by the new digit. You'd need to test if this is faster, not sure how fast division is compared to multiplication.

Comment: You can do this beforehand: x = map(int, x) and convert all the digits to int at once. What you do is that you perform this conversion multiple times per digit. This should save you some time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a generator expression within `max` function and a proper `key` function which calculate the product of your sub digits. For that aim you can use `map` function to convert the digits to integer and `reduce` (in python 3.X `functools.reduce`) to calculate the product of the integers.

```
>>> max((digits[i:i+13] for i in xrange(0, len(digits) - 12)), key=lambda x: reduce(mul, map(int, x)))
'5576689664895'
```

Note that if you have new line character between your digits you need to remove them using `str.replace()` method.

```
digits = digits.replace('\n', '')
```

## More optimized approach:

Since you are dealing with 13 digit each time you can use a container in order to preserve your digits in each iteration, and the best choice here would be `deque()` form `collections` module with `maxlen=13` which it's pop and push operation's order is O(1). Then you can calculate the product of the first 13 digit and at each push and pop your initial product should be divided by popped item and multiple by pushed item. and in each iteration you can just preserve the sequence with maximum product.

```
from operator import mul
from collections import deque
from copy import copy

def cal_max_prod(container, current_product):
    max_container = {'seq': copy(container), 'prod': current_product}
    for i in digits[13:]:
        popped_item = int(container.popleft())
        container.append(i)
        try:
            push_item = int(i)
            current_product = (current_product / popped_item) * push_item
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            if '0' not in container:
                current_product = reduce(mul, map(int, container))
        else:
            if current_product > max_container['prod']:
                max_container['prod'] = current_product
                max_container['seq'] = copy(container)

    return ''.join(max_container['seq'])
```

Demo:

```
container = deque(digits[:13], maxlen=13)
current_product = reduce(mul, map(int, container))
print cal_max_prod(container, current_product)
5576689664895
```

Comment: Just asking for curiosity is this the best code for this problem I mean in  terms of speed and memory occupied (suppose for a much greater sequence say ~1million)

Comment: In terms of speed, it is same as OP's code basically.

Comment: @jamessmith Since this code uses generator expression I thinks it's optimum in terms of memory use but because of multiple indexing and loops and using `reduce` I think it's not optimum in terms if run time.

Comment: @falsetru what do you think can be the best code in terms of speed

Comment: OP's code does not use list, so memory usages will not different significantly.

Comment: `xrange(0, len(digits) - 12)` over `range(len(digits))` if I am to nitpick.

Comment: @zamuz Indeed. Nice touch!

Comment: @Kasramvd Is it possible that your optimized approach could cause a zerodivision error if popped_item is zero?

Comment: after all the result is wrong the maximum number isn't 5576689664895 at all it's 23514624000 so idk wut you were doin here ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to improve efficiency you could notice that between the product of digits n to n+12 and n+1 to n+13, you have 12 common factors.

So let's note d<sub>i</sub> the n digits for i in [ 0, 999], and p<sub>i</sub> the products of m consecutive digits starting with d<sub>i</sub> (m=13 in your requirements):

- p<sub>i</sub> is defined for i in [0, 1000-m]
- p<sub>i+1</sub> = p<sub>i</sub> / d<sub>i</sub> * d<sub>i+m</sub> when d<sub>i</sub> != 0

On each iteration you only do one product and one division instead of 12 products, when d<sub>i</sub> != 0, which should occur 9 times out of 10 for a random serie

As always, optimize algorithm, before thinking to low level code optimization. But... code will be larger or more complex...

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity, instead of 13 digits, think of 3 digits. The first three digits are:

```
731
```

Their product is 21. The next three digits are:

```
316
```

The product is 18. We want an efficient algorithm, so one question that we must answer is: can we calculate the product of `731` from the product of `316` in constant time?

The answer is yes: if we look at the digits, to go from `731` to `316` we have removed 7 and added 6. But if we look at the product, we have *divided* by 7 and *multiplied* by 6. Instead of calculating 7×3×1, then 3×1×6, then 1×6×7, and so on (performing *n* multiplications every time) we can calculate the next product from the previous one (performing just 1 multiplication and 1 division).

This is a sketch for an efficient algorithm that runs in linear time:

```
def maxproduct(number, digits):
    """Calculate the maximum product of the n-adjacent digits of number."""
    zeros = 0
    product = 1
    result = 0

    # Calculate the first, initial product.
    for x in number[:digits]:
        x = int(x)
        if x:
            product *= int(x)
        else:
            # This digit is 0. This will make our product zero
            # too (losing information about other digits) and will
            # also cause trouble with division later. Instead of
            # storing the zero in the product, we increment a counter.
            zeros += 1

    if not zeros:
        # This product is the highest we have seen so far.
        result = product

    # Calculate the other products with the remaining digits.
    for i in range(digits, len(number)):
        # Digit to remove.
        x = int(number[i - digits])
        # Digit to add.
        y = int(number[i])

        if x:
            product //= x
        else:
            # The digit to remove is 0.
            zeros -= 1

        if y:
            product *= y
        else:
            zeros += 1

        if not zeros and product > result:
            result = product

    return result
```

Comment: Did you test the speed? And the fact that it's 13 digits and not 3 can have an impact on the timing.

Comment: @LtWorf: my answer has nothing to do with code speed, but deals with algorithmic efficiency

Comment: Since we are multiplying a constant number of digits, the final solution is O(n) anyway. So what you are trying to do is reduce the constant factor. And you are assuming that a division has the same weight as a multiplication. But this might not be the case. It is just an arbitrary assumption that you made, without backing it with anything.

Comment: @LtWorf: actually I'm assuming that 13 is not a constant

Answer (score 0):

Using numpy, if memory is not an issue. From benchmarks on his digits speed seems to be approx 10x faster than OP code:

```
import numpy as np
def no2(x,d=13):
    k = len(x)-d
    t = np.ones(k,dtype=int)
    xa = np.fromiter(map(int,tuple(x)),dtype=int)
    for i in range(d): #xrange on python2.x
        t *= xa[i:k+i]
    return np.max(t)
```

To get the digits that return maximum, replace `np.max(t)` with `x[np.argmax(t):np.argmax(t)+d]`.
example:

```
no2('123456789101234123412351235324234324234')
1244160
```

### Benchmarking

When benchmarking on string you provided I find:

```
#OP approach:
%timeit -n 100  no(x)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.49 ms per loop

#Kasramvd approach:
%timeit -n 100  no3=max((s[i:i+13] for i in range(0, len(s) - 12)), key=lambda x: reduce(mul, map(int, x)))
100 loops, best of 3: 4.22 ms per loop

#Andrea approach:
%timeit -n 100 no4(x,13) 
100 loops, best of 3: 777 µs per loop

#numpy approach:
%timeit -n 100  no2(x)
100 loops, best of 3: 315 µs per loop
```

#### When both memory and speed is an issue:

When benchmarking using a string 10^4 times longer(ie 10^7 digits):

```
#numpy
%timeit -n 10 no2(x5)
10 loops, best of 3: 2.2 s per loop

#OP code
%timeit -n 1 no(x5)
1 loop, best of 3: 37 s per loop

#Andrea code
%timeit -n 1 no4(x5,13)
1 loop, best of 3: 8.01 s per loop
```

Which is also a approx 10x improvement over OP code. So unless array cannot fit into RAM(but the string can) numpy performs better.

Answer (score 0):

```
 # I found this solution in this video  (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oSZZn7krnX0&list=PLO1D3YWS7ep3Zrh8B4SrhIsyxneg23x29&index=10)
 l='''
                73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
                96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
                85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
                12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
                66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
                62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
                30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
                70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
                65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
                52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
                53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
                83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
                82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
                16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
                17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
                24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
                07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
                84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
                05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
                71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450'''
    number = l.strip()
    number = number.replace('\n','')
    largest_mul = 0
    lenght = 13
    for i in range(len(number)):
       mul = 1
       for n in number[i:i+lenght]:
            mul *= int(n)
            if mul > largest_mul:
                largest_mul = mul
        
    print(largest_mul)
        # 23514624000
```

Answer (score -1):

```
data=list("
73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934\
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843\
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511\
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557\
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113\
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749\
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866\
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776\
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243\
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397\
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482\
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474\
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881\
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586\
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042\
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408\
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188\
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606\
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725\
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450")

print(len(data))

lst=list()

while True:

        x=list(data[0:13])

        pro=1

        for i in x:

            pro*=int(i)

        lst.append(pro)


        data.pop(0)

        if len(data)==12:

            break

print(max(lst))

print(len(data))

print(lst[0])
```